# How would I map my array of hashes for jquery autocomplete?

Tags: ruby, json, jquery-autocomplete

I have this ruby object

```
options = [
  {"ActionScript"=>"orange"},
  {"AppleScript"=>"orange"},
  {"Asp"=>"red"},
  {"BASIC"=>"green"},
  {"C"=>"blue"},
  {"C++"=>"purple"},
  {"Clojure"=>"green"},
  {"COBOL"=>"red"},
  {"ColdFusion"=>"red"},
  {"Erlang"=>"green"},
  {"Fortran"=>"orange"},
  {"Groovy"=>"green"},
  {"Haskell"=>"green"},
  {"Java"=>"green"},
  {"JavaScript"=>"brown"},
  {"Lisp"=>"purple"},
  {"Perl"=>"blue"},
  {"PHP"=>"red"},
  {"Python"=>"green"},
  {"Ruby"=>"green"},
  {"Scala"=>"green"},
  {"Scheme"=>"orange"}
]
```

and i'd like it to be mapped to this:

```
[{"name":"ActionScript","value":"orange"},{"name":"AppleScript","value":"orange"}...]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question was tagged json and jquery-autocomplete, but it does not appear to be *directly* related to none of them.

Comment: the map is json because of the : rather than => and it's related to jquery auto complete because of "name" and "value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'json'

options.map {|elem| elem.map {|k,v| {:name => k, :value => v}}}.flatten.to_json
```

Comment: I don't quite see why the `map` on `elem`.

Comment: I just love maps! Especially the National Geographic ones. And star maps. Map map, you can never have to many maps!

Comment: Er, I was right the first time. The inner map just lets you get at the  hash key/value paris, relying on the one key per hash. FWIW your version using `reduce` looks much cleaner.

Comment: I saw the edit, I wasn't trying to mislead you :-) yes, it works as it is, but conceptually it's a bit confusing, since the map is used just to extract the (key, value) of a hash with a single element. Thanks for the +1, you don't usually see that from the user of most voted answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
options.map do |option| 
  key, value = option.first
  {"name" => key, "value" => value} 
end # add .to_json if you want a JSON string
```

Also:

```
options.reduce(:merge).map { |k, v| {"name" => k, "value" => v} }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the to_json method,

```
 require 'json' 
 options = options.map {|elem| elem.map {|k,v| {:name => k, :value => v}}}.flatten 
 js_options = options.to_json
```

Comment: Why do you have this in erb tags? Certainly you wouldn't recommend putting the logic in the view?

Comment: yeh I don't, I was trying it to test, if generated the correct js, left the erb tags on.. :| edited